# Can you create undefined data by fseeking past EOF?

Tags: c++, c, fwrite, fseek

If you use `fseek` to go past the end of a file and then append data after the EOF, would the data in between the EOF and what you wrote be undefined?

For example in the code below, would there be 10 bytes of undefined data in the written file because of `randomLengthPastEOF`?

```
unsigned char *someText= "ExampleText";
int length = 11;
int randomLengthPastEOF  = 10;

FILE *output = fopen("/Example/FilePath", "wb");
fseek(input, randomLengthPastEOF ,SEEK_END);
fwrite(someText, 1, length, output);
```

I can't find a reference any where to what might happen so I assume it is undefined.

Comment: what exactly is `undefined data`?

Comment: Try it and find out? :) best way of doing things. You literally wrote the code right there to do it, why are you asking us? Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: On unix systems this will write NUL bytes.

Comment: @SouravGhosh - Data that isn't defined by a standard

Comment: and which data is defined by standards?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner - Because if it's undefined it might act like a certain way by chance rather than by designed behavior.

Specifically I have a "corrupted" file that has been generated with a PNG embedded within it. The file is generated in a way that's not as trivial in my given example but it's got the logic I described and I'm trying to figure out if it's because of the undefined behavior I have described.

Comment: @LukeLee - Thank you I checked the man pages and the note wasn't in it

Comment: Allowing access to random spots on the hard disk would be a security violation. A modern OS would clear the space before giving it to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

POSIX defines data in between to be zero bytes:
http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/3posix/fseek/

> The fseek() function shall allow the file-position indicator to be set beyond the  end  of existing  data  in  the    file. If data is later written at this point, subsequent reads of data in the gap shall return bytes with the value 0 until data is  actually  written  into the gap.

Comment: The system is a bit exotic so I will need to confirm it is POSIX compliant but I'm pretty sure it is. I'll have to look else where for the bug it seems.

Answer (score 5):

It'll all be zeros.  In fact, if you skip far enough to skip whole blocks UNIX will make what's called a sparse file, only the blocks you have written to are allocated, and if you later try to read from the blocks that were never written to, it doesn't read the disk, it just pretends there's a block of all zeros and returns the part of that you asked for.